# How to get the nearby monuments by coordinates in a radius?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps, bing-maps

I'm having coordinates using phone GPS and I'm using it for an android application. The user will take the photo of dirty area in any monument in our country and will send the photo and GPS coordinates so that we can clean the area.
The problem is, I want to know which monument is that and its image so that a person goes there and clean it. I've checked for google and bing APIs but I'm not able to find out how to do that. Suggest for the best way or solution to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the coordinates are given, you may want to use [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) which will convert your coordinates to its respected address/place. If a certain monument in your country is not registered in Google Maps, you may want to use Google Places API especially [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place?hl=en#add-place) this will enable your application to mark places not available in Google servers.

Comment: Unfortunately, [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) has been deprecated on June 30, 2017 and will stop working on June 30, 2018. So you cannot use this method anymore. For further details please refer to the corresponding [geo blog post](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html).